# Globo 3D clicável

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web, 3d

Estou pensando em fazer um projeto utilizando um globo 3D com a possibilidade de clicar nos países, mas não sei por onde começar.

Andei pesquisando e até o momento encontrei isso:

https://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe

Parece ser bem completo, mas não da a possibilidade de clique e não achei muito conteúdo para manipula-lo.

Alguém sabe de algum lugar que ensine a mexer nesse globo ou a criar um do zero? Sei que é algo muito complicado então qualquer ajuda é valida.

Comment: Você já usa o [ThreeJs](http://threejs.org/)?

Comment: já vi, mas nuca usei. Vou começar agora, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 4):

Bem, para início de conversa, quando se fala em 3D em javascript, aconselho-lhe logo a dar uma na biblioteca [**ThreeJs**](http://threejs.org/). Há uma gama enorme de exemplos completos com as mais variadas finalidades que podem lhe ajudar nessa difícil missão.

Ela trabalha com [`OpenGl`](https://www.opengl.org/) e [`WebGl`](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/). 
Você pode ver a compatibilidade destes no browser aqui: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

**Porque o que você deseja é tão complexo**

Quase todos os exemplos de globos terrestres 3Ds, como [este](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html), são apenas um objetos `sphere` com uma superfície que, ao invés de possuir uma textura, possui uma imagem manipulada para encaixar na superfície da esfera, se trata de um [*UV Mapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping), ou seja, é algo estático.

Como você disse que queria que os países fossem clicáveis, imagino que queira que ao passar o mouse ou ao clicar sobre eles, estes se destaquem de alguma forma, e aí que mora o problema. Para isso, deveria-se criar um objeto para cada país que se queira destacar, o que seria bastante difícil e ficaria feio, tenha certeza.

Devido a isso, o que você vai encontrar em javascript, são estas Terras que se pode apenas girar e ver de vários ângulos. Entretanto, é importante que fique sabido que essa limitação é referente a uma especificação detalhada como a sua, mas que o ThreeJs é, como já dito antes, extremamente completo.

Há alguns exemplos ([com este](http://earth.watype.net/en/globe/)) de algo semelhante com que você deseja em Flash, mas além de serem ultrapassados (flash), são de quase impossível manipulação.

**Criando a Esfera Estática do zero**

[Neste site](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/) há todo um passo a passo de como se criar um globo terrestre em `WebGl`. Aplicar o *Uv Mapping*, criar o auto relevo através de *Blend Modes* (modos de mesclagem), enfim... deixar bonitinha. Serve-te até para entender mais sobre a modelagem 3D, a lógica de texturas, etc.

Espero, apesar de não ter trago uma solução, que tenha ajudado.

**Boa sorte!** E qualquer dúvida...

Comment: Se ele tiver uma lista dos países clicáveis geolocalizados, seria possível colocar marcadores na esfera, e tratar o clique nesses marcadores.

Comment: Concordo @bfavaretto. O marcadores sim são possíveis, semelhante a [esse exemplo](http://earth.watype.net/en/globe/) em flash, porém em javascript. Pretendo arranjar um exemplo com estes marcadores. Você possui algum?

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho um exemplo. Fiz isso uma vez, anos atrás, mas foi com Flash.

Comment: É realmente difícil encontrar um, e fazer na mão...

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, acho que encontrei a solução, olha que site maneiro:  http://www.delimited.io/blog/2015/5/16/interactive-webgl-globes-with-threejs-and-d3